# Post to facebook page without conecting to facebook in client-side

Tags: php, facebook

I use the flowing code to post to my Facebook page but this code redirects user to Facebook to fetching Access Token as you can see.

```
$facebook=newFacebook(array(
'appId'=>$app_id,
'secret'=>$app_secret,
'cookie'=>true
));

$user=$facebook->getUser();

if(($facebook->getUser())==0)
{
header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('req_perms'=>'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,offline_access,manage_pages'))}");
exit();
}
else{
$accounts_list=$facebook->api('/me/accounts');
}

foreach($accounts_list['data']as$account){
if($account['id']==123456789){
$access_token=$account['access_token'];
}
}

$attachment['link']='article-url';

$facebook->api('/160145120705699/feed','POST',$attachment);
```

The problem is, facebook has been banned in Iran. Is there any other way to post to Facebook page without connecting to facebook in the client-side?

Comment: There isn't a way unless the user uses a proxy.

Comment: You can always use a server outside of Iran.

Comment: My server is outside of Iran.

Comment: Do you mean that it is not possible to make users to post to my page without involving users with Facebook?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it requires user's active access token that can be extended since offline_access is no longer working. So you have to store access token on server side and also have access to facebook from there. So instead of redirecting user to get token, you will get it from database and then set it to $facebook object with [setAccessToken()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-setAccessToken/) and do posting as usual

Answer (score 0):

Does the post have to appear to be coming from the users' Facebook? Does the user even *have* Facebook? Otherwise you could get an access token server side (representing you, or the app or the page itself, etc) and post with that (also server side, don't send the token over the wire, only the user's text!). All posts will appear to come from the same page/app/user, but at least the text inside the post is coming from Iran.

I was also thinking about asking the users Facebook username and password and login from the server, but that is not only is very unconventional and insecure, it also will probably not work, since Facebook will be suspicious when a user logs in from an entirely different geographical location.

Comment: The page and the app is mine and we are posting as page admin. Why it is necessary that user have Facebook account?
How can i get an access token server-side?